# Circle element is not accessing

Tags: dom, d3.js, geometry

I wish to do  circle animation using d3. i wish to show circle growing  on mouse hover. for this  i have used following code. the code runs without error how it does not produce any circle animation.  any advice where I am doing wrong. please see the code below

```
  var vis = d3.select(e).append("svg")
  .attr("width", svgwidth)
  .attr("height", svgheight);

   var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(sampleData);
   var circleEnter=circles.enter().append("g").append("circle");

    var circles = vis.selectAll("circle").data(sampleData);
    var circleEnter=circles.enter().append("g").append("circle");

    circleEnter.attr("cx", function (d,i) 
            {
             Cxs[i]= xRange (d.x);
             return xRange (d.x); 
             })

    .attr("cy", function (d,i) {
        Cys[i]= yRange (d.y); return yRange (d.y);
        })

    .attr("r", 20)
    .style("fill-opacity", .2)
    .style("fill", fillColor) 

    .on("mouseover", function(d,i)
            { 


        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r",30);
  }

     .on("mouseout", function(d,i)
            { 


        d3.select(this).select("circle").transition()
        .duration(750)
        .attr("r",20);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just `d3.select(this)` -- this will already select the `circle` element:

```
.on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
    d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("r",30);
}).on("mouseout", function(d,i) { 
    d3.select(this).transition()
    .duration(750)
    .attr("r",20);
})
```

Comment: thank you. it worked, however i am wondering what if i want to apply the same transition to its two neighbour circles. for example if i mouse over a circle i wish it surrounding circles reduce in size.  for that i used following  

     .on("mouseover", function(d,i) {
     d3.select(this).circles(i+1).transition()
     .duration(750)
     .attr("r",20);
but it  returns error. I would appreciate any suggestion. 
regards.

Comment: In that case I would assign IDs to the elements that make them easy to select this way, e.g. something based on the index: `.attr("id", function(d, i) { return "idx" + i; })` and then `d3.select("idx" + (i+1)).transition()...`.

Comment: thanks. i did use  your suggested coding, but i found it  not work.  i further invistaged this and found that it  did not created any objects with this ids (return "idx"+i) and to   check this i used d3.select("idx" + i).attr("id)
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAttribute'. any thought

Comment: Sorry, typo -- should be `d3.select("#idx" + (i+1))`.

Comment: thanks, i just figured out the same. it worked. once again thank you for your suggestions.